# Getting NullPointerException on FirebaseUser.getUid()

Tags: android, firebase, nullpointerexception, firebase-authentication

I am getting "NullPointerException:firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid() on null object reference" error. The thing is that my FirebaseUser.getUid() is not null. I checked this by using log.d and found the user's ID to match the one on firebase. So I don't know what the problem may be. Pls help

**Here is the code:**

```
//tabLayout sets up the tabs to switch from chats <--> user
    //viewPager allows swiping motion between tabs
    tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);


    firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //we need to create adapter using ViewPager --> create ViewPageAdapter
            ViewPageAdapter viewPageAdapter = new ViewPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            //counter for # of unread messages
            int unread = 0;

            //create chat objects from firebase data
            //----------------------------ERROR STARTS HERE--------------------------------
            for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Chat chat = snapshot.getValue(Chat.class);
                Log.d("firebaseUserID", firebaseUser.getUid());

                //if firebaseUser is the receiver of text and they have not opened text yet --> increment unread
                    if (chat.getReceiver().equals(firebaseUser.getUid()) && !chat.isSeen()) {
                        unread++;
                    }
            }
            //set on viewPager accordingly
            if(unread == 0) {
                //make ChatsFragment obj inside adapter
                viewPageAdapter.addFragment(new ChatsFragment(), "Chats");
            }
            else {
                //make ChatsFragment obj inside adapter
                viewPageAdapter.addFragment(new ChatsFragment(), "(" + unread + ") Chats");
            }

            //make UsersFragment obj inside adapter
            viewPageAdapter.addFragment(new UsersFragment(), "Users");
            //set adapter to ViewPager
            viewPager.setAdapter(viewPageAdapter);
            //set ViewPager to tabLayout
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

**Error message**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.moneymoves, PID: 31665
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.moneymoves.MainActivity$1.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:73)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:75)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:63)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:55)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
```

**And this is what my log function outputs**

D/firebaseUserID: XHYXsfwQJQXcy3lOhFeM08vwity1

**Thus, FirebaseUser should not be null right?**

Comment: Arguing with a compiler or runtime error is seldom useful. Put a breakpoint on the line that throws the exception, and once it hits that breakpoint in the debugger, check the value of the object you call `getUid()` on. It will be `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try declaring a `String firebaseUserId = firebaseUser.getUid();` and use it in required places.
Also, use `assert firebaseUser != null;` above the String declaration to avoid null object reference errors.

It should look like this:

```
assert firebaseUser != null;
String firebaseUserId = firebaseUser.getUid();
```